# UILabel tap gesture recognizer doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I know this is an often asked question but I have a specific case of the issue as I abstracted the tapGestureRecognizer so it can be re-used without initialiazing it everytime.

Here is how I use UITapGestureRecognizer on UIlabels :

In UILabel extension :

```
func setOnClickListener(action: @escaping (_: Any?) -> Void, clickedObject: Any? = nil){
        let tapRecogniser = ClickListener(target: self, action: #selector(onViewClicked), clickedObject: clickedObject, onClick: action)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecogniser)
    }
    
    @objc func onViewClicked(_ sender: ClickListener) {
        sender.onClick?(sender.clickedObject)
    }
```

The ClickListener class :

```
class ClickListener: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var onClick : ((_: Any?) -> Void)?
    var clickedObject: Any?
    
    init(target: Any?, action: Selector?, clickedObject: Any? = nil, onClick: ((_: Any?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.clickedObject = clickedObject
        self.onClick = onClick
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }
}
```

And here how I call it in my view :

```
class VoteBoxView: UIView {

  private var updateVoteButton: UILabel! = UILabel()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
  }
    
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

func initLayout() {
  self.addSubview(updateVoteButton)
  self.updateVoteButton.text = "Modifier"
  self.updateVoteButton.setToSecondaryText()
  self.updateVoteButton.setToSecondaryTextColor()
  self.updateVoteButton.underline()
  self.updateVoteButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
       make.top.equalTo(self).offset(15)
       make.right.equalTo(self)
  }
  self.initActions()
}

func initActions() {
        updateVoteButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        updateVoteButton.setOnClickListener(action: updateVote, clickedObject: nil)
    }

    func updateVote(clickedObject: Any?) {
        self.toggleResults(active: false)
    }
}
```

I definitely succeeded to make it work in other cases but there is no differences I can find that would cause it not to work here.

Comment: Post how you use `VoteBoxView` ?

Comment: I just add it as a ViewController subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set the correct constraints on my view so the tap was blocked by my ViewController view. I found out by adding colored background on everything.